# Akka camel endpoint behavior

Tags: java, apache-camel, akka

I am using akka java API and have the following producer:

```
public class ProvisioningResponseWriter extends UntypedProducerActor {
    private final String uri;

    public ProvisioningResponseWriter(String uri) {
        this.configProxy();  // configure http(s) proxy on camel context
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public Object onTransformOutgoingMessage(Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof String) {
            log.debug("Received: {}", (String) msg);
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return this.uri;
    }

}
```

The uri is something like http://somewhere.com

When the host at the URI is not responding for any reason, my app catches a "Stream Closed" exception and restarts the actor, which is fine and good. The problem is that if the "Stream Closed" happens more than a couple times, this actor doesn't seem to send any more message to the camel endpoint for about 5 minutes (confirmed by watching packets on the wire.) Is this an expected behavior? If yes, how do I change this behavior to always send message or reduce the back-off to just a few seconds?